# Custom video player in iOS with next video suggestions

Tags: ios, swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

Is it possible to create a custom video player in iOS? Like having custom bars and buttons?
And if yes, is it possible to add such a functionality like the YouTube suggestions for next video, right after the current one has stopped?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can use the AVPlayer to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that **yes it is possible**.

Use [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html) and build a custom view controller that handles showing the suggestion.